# Object Construction using Generics

Tags: java, oop, generics, constructor

Im having issues creating Objects using generics in order to test my rewritten methods, I think something is wrong with my constructor but im not entirely sure what.

I put the methods I believe are the main issues at the top, and the rest of the code under for context.
Any help is appreciated.

```
/**
     * Initializes an empty map.
     */
    public AbstractMiniMap() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.keys = new Object[CAPACITY];
        this.vals = new Object[CAPACITY];
        
    
    }
```

Object Creation in Main

Getting a "Cannot instantiate the type AbstractMiniMap" error, under the AbstractMiniMap after new.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         AbstractMiniMap<Double, Double> asd = new AbstractMiniMap<>(20,30);
        
    }
```

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

/**
 * This class provides a skeletal implementation of the {@code MiniMap}
 * interface. It provides separate arrays for the keys and values of the map, as
 * well as implementations of the {@code MiniMap} accessor methods.
 * 
 * <p>
 * A functioning {@code MiniMap} implementation can be created by extending this
 * class and implementing the {@code push} and {@code remove} methods in the
 * subclass.
 *
 * @param <K> the type of keys maintained by this map
 * @param <V> the type of mapped values
 */
public abstract class AbstractMiniMap<K, V> implements MiniMap<K, V> {
    
    /**
     * The array of keys.
     */
    protected Object keys[];
    
    /**
     * The array of values.
     */
    protected Object vals[];
    
    /**
     * The number of mappings currently in this map.
     */
    protected int size;

    private static final int CAPACITY = 16;

    /**
     * Initializes an empty map.
     */
    public AbstractMiniMap() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.keys = new Object[CAPACITY];
        this.vals = new Object[CAPACITY];
        
    
    }

    /**
     * Returns the capacity (maximum number of elements) that this map can hold at
     * any one time.
     * 
     * @return the capacity of this map
     */
    public final int capacity() {
        return CAPACITY;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of key-value mappings held by this map.
     * 
     * @return the number of key-value mappings held by this map
     */
    public final int size() {
        return this.size;
    }

    /**
     * HINT: VERY USEFUL METHOD. You don't have to implement this method, but it
     * prevents a lot of code duplication.
     * 
     * Returns the index of the element equal to the specified key in
     * {@code this.keys} if such an element exists, or {@code -1} otherwise.
     * 
     * @param key a key to search for
     * @return the index of the element equal to the specified key in
     *         {@code this.keys} if such an element exists, or {@code -1} otherwise
     */
    protected int indexOfKey(Object key) {
        int counter = -1;
        for (Object i: this.keys){
            counter++;
            if (i.equals(key)) {
                return counter;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * HINT: VERY USEFUL METHOD. You don't have to implement this method, but it
     * prevents a lot of code duplication.
     * 
     * Returns the index of the element equal to the specified value in
     * {@code this.vals} if such an element exists, or {@code -1} otherwise.
     * 
     * @param value a value to search for
     * @return the index of the element equal to the specified value in
     *         {@code this.vals} if such an element exists, or {@code -1} otherwise
     */
    protected int indexOfValue(Object value) {
        int counter = -1;
                for(Object i:this.vals) {
                    counter++;
                    if(i.equals(value)) {
                        return counter;
                    }
                }
                return -1;

    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the map contains a mapping for the specified key. More
     * formally, returns true if and only if this map has a key {@code k} such that
     * {@code k.equals(key)} is true.
     * 
     * @param key a key to search for in this map
     * @return true if this map contains a mapping for the specified key
     */
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        // HINT: Consider using indexOfKey....
        int response = indexOfKey(key);
        if (response != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        

    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the map contains one or more keys that map to the specified
     * value. More formally, returns true if and only if this map has a value
     * {@code v} such that {@code v.equals(value)} is true.
     * 
     * @param value a value to search for in this map
     * @return true if this map contains one or more mappings for the specified
     *         value
     */
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        // HINT: Consider using indexOfValue....
        int response = indexOfValue(value);
        if(response != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Returns the value that the specified key maps to, or {@code null} if
     * {@code containsKey(key)} is false.
     * 
     * @param key the key to search for
     * @return the value that the specified key maps to, or {@code null} if the map
     *         does not contain the specified key
     */
    public V get(Object key) {
        // HINT: Maybe use indexOfKey....
        int response = indexOfKey(key);
        if(response == -1) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            V t = (V) this.vals[response];
            return t;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this map. The returned string contains the
     * key-value pairs as strings enclosed in braces ({@code "{}"}). Adjacent
     * mappings are separated by the characters {@code ", "} (comma and space). Each
     * key-value mapping is rendered as the key followed by an equals sign
     * ({@code "="}) followed by the associated value. For example, a map containing
     * a string key {@code "a"} mapped to the integer value {@code 100} and a string
     * key {@code "b"} mapped to the integer value {@code 200} would have the string
     * representation:
     * 
     * <p>
     * {@code "{a=100, b=200}"} or {@code "{b=100, a=200}"}
     * 
     * <p>
     * depending on how the mappings are stored in the map.
     * 
     * 
     * @return a string representation of this map
     */
    public String toString() {
        // HINT: Use a java.util.StringJoiner object to help build the string
        

    }

    /**
     * STUDENTS SHOULD NOT USE THIS METHOD.
     * 
     * <p>
     * Returns a set of keys equal to the set held by this map in the order that
     * they appear in {@code this.keys}. For testing purposes only.
     * 
     * @return a set of keys held by this map in the order that they appear in
     *         {@code this.keys}
     */
    public Set<K> keys() {
        return A6Utils.getKeys(this.keys);
    }

    /**
     * STUDENTS SHOULD NOT USE THIS METHOD.
     * 
     * <p>
     * Returns a list of values equal to the list held by this map in the order that
     * they appear in {@code this.vals}. For testing purposes only.
     * 
     * @return a list of values equal to the list held by this map in the order that
     *         they appear in {@code this.vals}
     */
    public List<V> values() {
        return A6Utils.getValues(this.vals);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         AbstractMiniMap<Double, Double> asd = new AbstractMiniMap<>(20,30);
        
    }
    
}
```

Tried casting to object on right side of equals sign.

Comment: If you’re doing something as advanced as writing your own map implementation, I assume you are aware that abstract classes cannot be directly instantiated.

Comment: The professor assigns skeletons and has us fill it in, trust me I don't like the structure either as I don't understand a lot of what is going on. All that is to do on my side is fill in the methods everything else was given.

Comment: The JavaDoc even states "A functioning {@code MiniMap} implementation can be created by extending this class and implementing the {@code push} and {@code remove} methods in the subclass.". Did you extend the class and implement the `push` and `remove` methods?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the class declaration, the `AbstractMiniMap` is an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractMiniMap<K, V> implements MiniMap<K, V>
```

Abstract classes can't be instantiated in Java since abstract classes are defined to be abstract super-classes that should not be instantiated on their own but further implemented in a sub-class.

### Possible Solutions

#### Anonymous sub-class

In your example, you might be able to instantiate the AbstractMiniMap with an anonymous inline sub-class like this: `new AbstractMiniMap<>() {};`. That is possible because `AbstractMiniMap` does not contain any abstract methods that would have been to be implemented by sub-classes.

#### Un-abstract

On the other hand, you could also just remove the `abstract` from the class declaration, if you want the class to be instantiable. But then you would also have to remove the "Abstract" prefix of `AbstractMiniMap` in order to comply with common naming conventions.

#### Clean Solution

The clean solution (if you want the `AbstractMiniMap` to remain `abstract`) would be to create a normal sub-class of it and instantiate this one.

Either

```
public class DoubleMiniMap extends AbstractMiniMap<Double, Double> {
}
```

with `MiniMap<Double, Double> map = new DoubleMiniMap();`

Or

```
public class GenericMiniMap<K, V> extends AbstractMiniMap<K, V> {
}
```

with `MiniMap<Double, Double> map = new GenericMiniMap<>();`

Comment: Ah thank you for the quick response! I wasn't aware of the abstract class part, that makes sense since we are implementing it into other classes.

Comment: Oh, I have just realized that the abstract class probably does not implement all methods of the interface `MiniMap`, so you would have to use my last option to extend the abstract class and implement the missing methods there (e.g., push, remove).